# Selecting record that fulfills a condition but don't want to consider the condition, need to consider the other records thats being matched

Tags: mysql, sql

im practicing with SQL and have created this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A ( PROGRAM_ID    varchar (265) ,
SERIES_ID    varchar (265) ,
SEASON_ID    varchar (265) ,
ACCOUNT_ID   varchar (265) ,
START_DATE_EST   date, 
END_DATE_EST     date, 
ACCOUNT_HOME_COUNTRY     varchar (265) ,
PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE   varchar (265) ,
SEASON_FULL_TITLE    varchar (265) ,
SERIES_FULL_TITLE    varchar (265) ,
PROGRAM_TYPE     varchar (265) ,
SEASON_NUMBER    int,
EPISODE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER  int,
EPISODE_SERIES_SEQUENCE_NUMBER   int,
RUNTIME  bigint,
WATCH_LENGTH_MS  bigint,
IS_STREAM    int,
IS_COMPLETED_STREAM  int
  
);
```

with this insert data

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('fre123-34534', 'jlk456-nm-56', 'tre-765-fd', 'jewq345-b3', '2021-01-01','2021-01-01', 'MX', 'Chapter 9: The Marshall', 'The Mandalorian Season 2', 'The Mandalorian', 'episode', 2, 1, 9, 3244, 167251, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('qwe-567-dsa', 'jlk456-nm-56', 'hjfg-123-re', 'asd-345-h', '2021-06-06', '2021-06-06', 'BR', 'Chapter 1: The Mandalorian', 'The Mandalorian Season 1', 'The Mandalorian', 'episode', 1, 1, 1, 2377, 30005, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('mrvl-456-tre', 'null', 'null', 'asd-345-h', '2021-06-15', '2021-06-15', 'MX', 'Ice Age: Dawn Of The Dinosaurs', 'null', 'null', 'movie',0 ,0 ,0 , 5797, 4620000, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('2b81a' ,'null' ,'null' ,'43116' ,'2021-06-16' ,'2021-06-16' ,'BR' ,'Snow White and The Seven Dwarfs' ,'null' ,'null' ,'movie' ,0 ,0 ,0 ,5077 ,0 ,0 ,0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('8a0f2' ,'886E-' ,'51B3-' ,'41d0c' ,'2021-06-11' ,'2021-06-11' ,'MX' ,'Alexs Choice' ,'Wizards of Waverly Place' ,'Wizards of Waverly Place' ,'episode' ,1 ,7 ,7 ,1443 ,922667 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('ae5e7' ,'468B-' ,'6173-' ,'add25' ,'2021-07-02' ,'2021-07-02' ,'BR' ,'Hawaii Pug-Oh / A.R.F.' ,'Puppy Dog Pals' ,'Puppy Dog Pals' ,'episode' ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1525 ,1420719 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('ae5e7' ,'468B-' ,'6173-' ,'add25' ,'2021-07-02' ,'2021-07-02' ,'BR' ,'Hawaii Pug-Oh / A.R.F.' ,'Puppy Dog Pals' ,'Puppy Dog Pals' ,'episode' ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1525 ,1420719 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('04ff0' ,'6861-' ,'780B-' ,'df57d' ,'2021-06-28' ,'2021-06-28' ,'MX' ,'Lamentis' ,'Loki Season 1' ,'Loki' ,'episode' ,1 ,3 ,3 ,2543 ,1952888 ,1 ,0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('77c78' ,'A9C2-' ,'5006-' ,'72d4c' ,'2021-07-02' ,'2021-07-02' ,'MX' ,'Sleepwalkin' ,'Mickey Mouse (Shorts)' ,'Mickey Mouse (Shorts)' ,'episode' ,1 ,14 ,14 ,321 ,226605 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('eabca' ,'B26A-' ,'65AC-' ,'59548' ,'2021-06-23' ,'2021-06-23' ,'BR' ,'EPISODE 219' ,'ONCE (YR 3 2018/19 EPS 161-220)' ,'O11CE' ,'episode' ,3 ,59 ,219 ,1376 ,981426 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('dbe51' ,'null' ,'null' ,'7414f' ,'2021-06-20' ,'2021-06-20' ,'BR' ,'Luca' ,'null' ,'null' ,'movie' ,0 ,0 ,0 ,6062 ,450083 ,1 ,0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('78356' ,'A307-' ,'F03B-' ,'071fa' ,'2021-06-27' ,'2021-06-27' ,'MX' ,'Point of No Return' ,'Star Wars: The Clone Wars' ,'Star Wars: The Clone Wars' ,'episode' ,5 ,13 ,101 ,1537 ,1323790 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('04ff0' ,'6861-' ,'780B-' ,'107e4' ,'2021-06-23' ,'2021-06-23' ,'AR' ,'Lamentis' ,'Loki Season 1' ,'Loki' ,'episode' ,1 ,3 ,3 ,2543 ,1891918 ,1 ,0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('d657a' ,'3D23-' ,'EBED-' ,'cdb2c' ,'2021-06-25' ,'2021-06-25' ,'AR' ,'outfoX' ,'The Gifted' ,'The Gifted' ,'episode' ,1 ,9 ,9 ,2670 ,2564518 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('dbe51' ,'null' ,'null' ,'64fda' ,'2021-06-22' ,'2021-06-22' ,'MX' ,'Luca' ,'null' ,'null' ,'movie' ,0 ,0 ,0 ,6062 ,5448827 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('b5e6b' ,'CC3F-' ,'94B7-' ,'5216c' ,'2021-06-16' ,'2021-06-16' ,'MX' ,'Band-A-Rooney' ,'Liv and Maddie' ,'Liv and Maddie' ,'episode' ,2 ,19 ,40 ,1485 ,680495 ,1 ,1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('d500' ,'a600' ,'33sc-' ,'6ab3c' ,'2021-06-20' ,'2021-06-20' ,'AR' ,'Avengers End Game' ,'null' ,'null' ,'movie' ,1 ,2 ,2 ,3269 ,1605864 ,1 ,0);
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES ('d4081' ,'6861-' ,'780B-' ,'6ab3c' ,'2021-06-20' ,'2021-06-20' ,'AR' ,'The Variant' ,'Loki Season 1' ,'Loki' ,'episode' ,1 ,2 ,2 ,3269 ,1605864 ,1 ,0);
```

how i can check what other content(PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE) watched those that streamed a program, for example, Loki? based on the 2 last insert(ACCOUNT_ID = '6ab3c') in this case, i mean, i wanna show 'Avengers End Game' and not

i was trying something like this:

```
select PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE
from TABLE_A
where PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE in (select * from TABLE_A where IS_STREAM = 1 and SERIES_FULL_TITLE='Loki') 
and SERIES_FULL_TITLE <> 'Loki'
```

i search over here but couldnt solve it, please if someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect subquery.

```
select PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE
from TABLE_A
where PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE in (select PROGRAM_FULL_TITLE  from TABLE_A where IS_STREAM = 1 and 
SERIES_FULL_TITLE='Loki' order by ACCOUNT_ID DESC LIMIT 2) 
and SERIES_FULL_TITLE <> 'Loki'
```

Comment: I tried the code and it didnt work too, returns no value, its something like, first include the account that had streamed Loki and after that outside the subquerie exclude it from the result and just incluide the other content but doesnt know how to pass it properly to the sentence.

Comment: since the main query excluding the results on 'Loki'

Comment: can you please share what will the output?

Comment: Already solve it, the approach you give me was correct, i just change "where account_id in(select account_id)" with this first validates if  the account watches Loki and after excludes just the program. Thank you very much!